# Calculus Question: $\int_2^\infty\frac{\log^3(x-1)}{x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have just taken calculus quiz but I could not find  $\displaystyle \int_2^\infty\frac{\log^3(x-1)}{x^2}dx$? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, my tutor gave us hints about this question.

1. Use Taylor series
2. $\displaystyle \zeta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$

Those the hints that she gave to us.

Comment: Were you supposed to evaluate it, or just decide whether it converges? The value of the integral can be represented in terms of [$\zeta(3)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%28x+-+1%29^3+%2F+x^2+from+2+to+inf). If you want to check convergence only, then a useful bound is that $\log^3(x - 1) < \sqrt x$ for large enough $x$.

Comment: What exactly was the quiz ?

Comment: Is $\log$ base 10? Or base $e$?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I edit my question.

Comment: @T.Bongers I edit my question.

Comment: @TylerHG Base e. It's a common log notation in my college.

Comment: @Venus: Its a common notation for base 10 in some places.

Comment: @PranavArora Thank you for your edit :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the substitution $x-1=t$ to obtain:
$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\log^3t}{(1+t)^2}\,dt$$
With the substitution $t=1/u$, the above integral is:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{-\log^3 u}{(1+u)^2}\,du$$
Next, use the following series representation,
$$\frac{1}{(1+u)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (n+1)u^n$$
to obtain:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{-\log^3 u}{(1+u)^2}\,du=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(n+1)\int_0^1 \log^3u \,u^n\,du$$
Next use the substitution $\log u=-x$ to get:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(n+1)\int_0^{\infty} x^3e^{-(n+1)x}\,dx$$
With another substitution $(n+1)x=y$, you should get:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^3}\int_0^{\infty} y^3e^{-y}\,dy$$
Recoginse that $\int_0^{\infty} y^3e^{-y}\,dy=\Gamma(4)=3!$ (you can show this using integration by parts if you don't like the Gamma function), hence
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^3}\int_0^{\infty} y^3e^{-y}\,dy=6\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^3}$$
It is easy to show that:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^3}=\frac{3\zeta(3)}{4}$$
Hence, our final answer is:
$$\boxed{\dfrac{9\zeta(3)}{2}}$$

Comment: Your answer seems correct but why did you make a lot of substitutions to find the integral? It's hard for me to follow your idea. Can we just use Taylor series for $log^3(x-1)$? BTW, I appreciate your answer

Comment: I don't think there would a nice series representation for $\log^3(x-1)$ but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Venus:  And to answer your other question as to why I used so many substitutions, my main idea was to somehow get the limits from 0 to 1 so that I could use the series representation for $1/(1+t)^2$. Once I used the substitution $x-1=t$, it immediately became obvious what should be the next substitution, do you see why?

Comment: OK, give me time to think your idea first. Thanks for your answer. BTW, can you edit my question? It seems I did wrong for the summation notation and I don't how to do like yours

Comment: I think I have found the better substitution: $x=1+e^{-t}$ :)

Answer (score 3):

By substitutions, the following integrals are equivalent:
\begin{align*}
  \int_{2}^{\infty} \, \frac{\log^3(x-1)}{x^2}\, dx &= \int_{1}^{\infty} \, \frac{\log^3(x)}{(1+x)^2} \, dx\\
&= -\int_{0}^{1} \, \frac{\log^3(x)}{(1+x)^2}\, dx \tag 1
\end{align*}

$(1)$ can be written as a sum, consider:

\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{1} \, \frac{x^a}{(1+x)^2} dx &= \int_{0}^{1} \, \sum_{n\ge 0} (-1)^n (n+1)\, x^{a+n} \, dx\\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} \int_{0}^{1} \, (-1)^n (n+1)\, x^{a+n} \, dx\\
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} (-1)^n \frac{(n+1)}{a+n+1}\tag 2
\end{align*}
Differentiate $(2)$ w.r.t a thrice and set $a=0$, and from $(1)$,
\begin{align*}
  \int_{2}^{\infty} \, \frac{\log^3(x-1)}{x^2}\, dx &= 6\, \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^3}\\
&= \frac{9}{2} \zeta{(3)} \approx 5.40925606421817428
\end{align*}
So, a general result looks like:
\begin{align*}
  \int_{2}^{\infty} \, \frac{\log^n(x-1)}{x^2}\, dx &= \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right)n!\, \zeta{(n)}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{2}^{\infty}{\ln^{3}\pars{x - 1} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{2}^{\infty}%
> {\ln^{3}\pars{x - 1} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln^{3}\pars{x} \over \pars{x + 1}^{2}}\,\dd x
> =\int_{1}^{0}{\ln^{3}\pars{1/x} \over \pars{1/x + 1}^{2}}
> \,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{x} \over \pars{1 + x}^{2}}\,\dd x}
> \end{align}

With $\ds{0 < \epsilon < 1}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{-\int_{\epsilon}^{1}%
{\ln^{3}\pars{x} \over \pars{1 + x}^{2}}\,\dd x}
=-\,{\ln^{3}\pars{\epsilon} \over 1 + \epsilon}
-\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x}\,\bracks{3\ln^{2}\pars{x}\,{1 \over x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\ln^{3}\pars{\epsilon} \over 1 + \epsilon}
-3\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
+3\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-\,{\ln^{3}\pars{\epsilon} \over 1 + \epsilon} + \ln^{3}\pars{\epsilon}
+3\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> With the limit $\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{2}^{\infty}%
> {\ln^{3}\pars{x - 1} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}
> =3\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
> =-3\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{1 + x}\bracks{2\ln\pars{x}\,{1 \over x}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-6\int_{0}^{-1}\ln\pars{-x}\,{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
> =6\int_{0}^{-1}\ln\pars{-x}{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
> =-6\int_{0}^{-1}{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-6\int_{0}^{-1}{\rm Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
> =-6\,{\rm Li}_{3}\pars{-1}
> =-6\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{3}}
> \\[3mm]&=-6\bracks{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{3}}
> -\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}^{3}}}
> =-6\bracks{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{3}}
> -\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}}
> +\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n}^{3}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-6\braces{2\bracks{{1 \over 8}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}}}
> -\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}}}
> ={9 \over 2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{3}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{9 \over 2}\,\zeta\pars{3}} \approx {\tt 5.4093}
> \end{align}

$\ds{{\rm Li_{s}}\pars{z}}$ is the
[PolyLogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) and we used well known properties of them as explained in the above cited link.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to solve. From @Pranav Arora, we know
$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{(1+x)^2}dx=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{(1+u)^2}du. $$
Let
$$ I(\alpha)=\int_0^1\frac{u^\alpha}{(1+u)^2}du. $$
Clearly
$$ I'''(0)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{(1+u)^2}du. $$
Since
\begin{eqnarray*}
I(\alpha)&=&\int_0^1\frac{u^\alpha}{(1+u)^2}du=\int_0^1u^\alpha\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)u^{n}du\\
&=&\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)u^{n+\alpha}du\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{n+\alpha+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
the rest is the same as @gar's answer.

Comment: Thanks! But a bit typo in the first line. +1 anyway. :)

Comment: @Venus. The typo is fixed. Thanks for pointing.